# git push after git revert -m 1, doesn't push anything

Tags: git, bitbucket

A peer developer accidentally merged 'master' over a side branch 'feature_x' using www.bitbucket.org's online interface. 'feature_x' was forked from master several iterations ago and some considerable wrk has gone into it since. That merge was hence unintended, and is possibly incomplete, as it appears in BitBucket as greyed out.

I'm trying to undo it now; I've done a `git pull` to get up to date (and this merge is the most recent commit) - I've switched to the feature branch , followed by a `git revert -m 1 <hash>`. Git has done the revert locally, and I can see it in the git log, but when I do a `git push` it says "Everything up to date" and nothing changes in the list of commits that www.BitBucket.org shows..

```
$ git log
commit 33333333
Author: CJ
Date:   Mon Oct 30 12:25:55 2017 +0000

    Revert "Merged master into feature_x"

    This reverts commit 22222222, reversing
    changes made to ffffffff.

commit 22222222
Merge: ffffffff aaaaaaaa
Author: PD
Date:   Mon Oct 30 11:31:39 2017 +0000

    Merged master into feature_x

commit ffffffff
Author: ZZ
Date:   Sun Oct 15 14:38:59 2017 +0100

    Some work blah blah
```

What do I need to do to push these changes? Is nothing pushing because a revert isn't really a change unless I subsequently build on it with code changes?

Comment: well you can do a minimal change after git reset, then commit it and push --force.

Comment: Hi hector, this helped - thanks. I made a minimal change, and pushed only to get an error mentioning '(no branch):(no somethingelse)' which made me realise i'd never actually properly checked out the broken branch

Comment: Cool. Glad I helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was probably an error caused by my having a mixed work mode: I usually use SourceTree but I couldn't use it to revert this merge, because (as of 2.1.2.5) it doesn't have a way to specify which merge parent to use as a reference to revert to with the `-m N` when reverting a merge.. You just get an error when ST invokes the git command line without specifying the `-m` argument..

I'd thus dropped to command line to do it, but I had never actually checked out a local version of the `feature_x` branch, I'd just used SourceTree's "checkout existing" option to switch branch, which I think meant I had a local head that didn't point to anything remotely..